merge queries in microsoft graph api
Hello i have two queries to microsoft graph:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf?$count=true&$filter=id in ('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
the first one returns just the information of the user, the second if the user belongs to a given group.
how can i merge them in a single query to graph?
many thanks

From OData point of view, you can expand memberOf and apply inner filter like
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$expand=memberOf($filter=id eq 'xxx')

but it seems, that the Graph API doesn't support inner filter for memberOf and returns all groups.
Only way is to expand memberOf and apply filtering on the client
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$expand=memberOf

